# Set canvas image CSS image-rendering property

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am using angular 8 and I want to set css property:

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

to my image which is in canvas.

I tried with:

```
let image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
   canvasElement.width = image.width;
   canvasElement.height = image.height;

   canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
this.image.style.imageRendering = 'pixelated';
image.src = 'some base64 image';
```

I also tried to set this property in scss file like:

```
canvas {
   image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

But nothing works, where I am wrong ?

Comment: In what way is it not working? What browsers have you tested in? Have you checked to see if the style is applied in devtools?

Comment: You comment force to do test one more time. You are right, it works when I set property to the canvas element with css class. It was hard to notice since I test it on image with high resolution. When I took image of small resolution it is easy to see that it is fine.
Thank you for helped me to realize mistake by my own.